# How does Bash process a command line?

Tags: bash

From [Learning the Bash Shell by Newham](https://books.google.com/books?id=dzBCH3x6fYEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT196#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Each line that the shell reads from the standard input or a script is
>   called a pipeline; it contains one or more commands separated by zero
>   or more pipe characters (|). For each pipeline it reads, **the shell
>   breaks it up into commands**, sets up the I/O for the pipeline, then
>   does **the following for each command** (Figure 7-1):
>
> 1. Splits the command into tokens that are separated by the fixed set of metacharacters: SPACE, TAB, NEWLINE, ;, (, ), <, >, **|**, and &. Types
>      of tokens include words, keywords, I/O redirectors, and semicolons.

1. After the shell breaks a pipeline into commands separated by `|`, why is `|` still listed as a metacharacter which separate tokens in each command? Can `|` appear in each command?
2. The Bash Manual says that when a bash shell runs a pipeline, it forks a subshell to run each command in a pipeline.

   For each command in a pipeline, which shell "does the following for each command": the subshell forked for the command, or the original shell?

Answer (score 1):

- The pipe character `|` is a meta character because it ends a word that is not quoted. This is needed to make the shell language easy to understand.
- The way shells create the various processes for a pipeline is not standardized and differs between implementations.

The Bourne Shell originally did create a `sub-shell` that then becomes the parent of all processes of a pipeline and finally starts the rightmost program in the pipeline. This is the method that needs less code than other methods and that permits to implement job-control simple.

Bash works in a similar way.

Ksh93 makes every process from a pipeline a direct child of the original shell.