# Why isn't `|` treated literally in a glob pattern?

Tags: bash

My question comes from [How does storing the regular expression in a shell variable avoid problems with quoting characters that are special to the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382054/how-does-storing-the-regular-expression-in-a-shell-variable-avoid-problems-with#comment679291_382157).

1. Why is there an error:

   ```
   $ [[ $a = a|b ]]  
   bash: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `|'
   bash: syntax error near `|b'
   ```

   Inside `[[ ... ]]` the second operand of `=` is expected to be a
   globbing pattern.

   Is `a|b` not a valid globbing pattern? Can you point out which
   syntax rule it violates?
2. Some comment below points out that `|` is interpreted as pipe.

   Then changing `=` for glob pattern to `=~` for regex pattern make
   `|` work

   ```
   $ [[ $a =~ a|b ]]
   ```

   I learned from [Learning Bash](https://books.google.com/books?id=dzBCH3x6fYEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT196#v=onepage&q&f=false) p180 in [my previous post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279644/674) that `|` is recognized as pipe at the beginning of
   interpretation, even before any other steps of interpretation (including 
   parse the conditional expressions in the examples). So how can
   `|` be recognized as regex operator when using `=~`, without being recognized as pipe
   in invalid use, just as when using `=`? That makes me think that the syntax error in part 1 doesn't mean that `|` is interpreted as a pipe.

   > Each line that the shell reads from the standard input or a script is called a pipeline; it contains one or more commands separated by zero or more pipe characters (|). For each pipeline it reads, the shell breaks
   >   it up into commands, sets up the I/O for the pipeline, then does the following for each command (Figure 7-1):

Thanks.

Comment: Note that in some versions of bash, extglob parsing (where `|` is special) is on **by default** in the right-hand side of `[[ $var = $pattern ]]`. It would be interesting to isolate the versions and `shopt` option configurations where this behavior is seen -- if it's only those where `extglob` is on, either by default or explicit configuration, well, there we are.

Comment: BTW, if you wanted to somewhat more comprehensively rule out the case of the pipe character interfering with a prior stage of parsing (which I agree isn't happening, but it's not as obvious to the reader as it could be), you'd use `pattern='a|b'` and then expand `$pattern` unquoted on the RHS.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that was the point being made in [the Q&A](/q/382054) which this question is a follow-up to.

Comment: Ahh -- the context makes sense; and your answer here is outstanding. Thank you on both counts.

Comment: Tim, dijd any of the answers below answer your question? Please consider accepting one if so. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

There's no good reason why

```
[[ $a = a|b ]]
```

Should report an error instead of testing whether $a is the `a|b` string, while `[[ $a =~ a|b ]]` doesn't return an error.

The only reason is that `|` is generally (outside and inside `[[ ... ]]`) a special character. In that `[[ $a =` position, `bash` expects a type of token that is a normal *WORD* like the arguments or the targets of redirections in a normal shell command line (but as if the `extglob` option had been enabled since bash 4.1).

(by *WORD* here, I refer to a *word* in an hypothetical shell grammar like [the one described by the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02), that is something that the shell would parse as one token in a simple shell command line, not other definition of words like the English one of a sequence of letters or a sequence of non-spacing characters. `foo"bar baz"`, `$(echo x y)`, are two such *WORD*s).

In a normal shell command line:

```
echo a|b
```

Is `echo a` piped to `b`. `a|b` is not a *WORD*, it's three tokens: a `a` *WORD*, a `|` token and a `b` *WORD* token.

When used in `[[ $a = a|b ]]`, `bash` expects a *WORD* which it gets (`a`), but then finds an unexpected `|` token  which causes the error.

Interestingly, `bash` doesn't complain in:

```
[[ $a = a||b ]]
```

Because it's now a `a` token followed by a `||` token followed by `b`, so it's parsed the same way as:

```
[[ $a = a || b ]]
```

Which is testing that `$a` is `a` or that the `b` string is non-empty.

Now, in:

```
[[ $a =~ a|b ]]
```

`bash` can't have the same parsing rule. Having the same parsing rule would mean that the above would give an error and  that one would need to quote that `|` to ensure `a|b` is a single *WORD*. But, since bash 3.2, if you do:

```
[[ $a =~ 'a|b' ]]
```

That's no longer matching against the `a|b` regexp but against the `a\|b` regexp. That is, shell quoting has the side effect of removing the special meaning of regexp operators. It's a feature, so the behaviour is similar to the `[[ $a = "?" ]]` one, but wildcard patterns (used in `[[ $a = pattern ]]`) are shell *WORDS* (used in globs for instance), while regexps are not.

So `bash` has to treat all the extended regexp operators that are otherwise normally special shell characters like `|`, `(`, `)` differently when parsing an argument of the `=~` operator.

Still, note that while

```
 [[ $a =~ (ab)*c ]]
```

now works,

```
 [[ $a =~ [)}] ]]
```

doesn't. You need:

```
 [[ $a =~ [\)}] ]]
 [[ $a =~ [')'}] ]]
```

Which in previous versions of `bash` would incorrectly match on backslash. That one was fixed, but

```
 [[ $a =~ [^]')'] ]]
```

Does *not* match on backslash like it should for instance. Because `bash` fails to realise that `)` is within the brackets, so escapes the `)` to result in a `[^]\)]` regexp that matches on any character but `]`, `\` and `)`.

`ksh93` has much worse bugs on that front.

In `zsh`, it's a normal shell word that is expected and quoting regexp operators doesn't affect the meaning of regexp operators.

```
[[ $a =~ 'a|b' ]]
```

Is matching against the `a|b` regexp.

That means the `=~` can also be added to the `[`/`test` command:

```
[ "$a" '=~' 'a|b' ]
test "$a" '=~' 'a|b'
```

(also work in `yash`. The `=~` needs to be quoted in `zsh` as `=something` is a special shell operator there).

bash 3.1 used to behave like `zsh`. It changed in 3.2, presumably to align with `ksh93` (even though `bash` was the shell that first came up with `[[ =~ ]]`), but you can still do `BASH_COMPAT=31` or `shopt -s compat31` to revert to the previous behaviour (except that while `[[ $a =~ a|b ]]` would return an error in `bash` 3.1, it doesn't anymore in `bash -O compat31` with newer versions of `bash`).

Hope it clarifies why I said the rules were confusing and why using:

```
[[ $a =~ $var ]]
```

helps including with portability to other shells.

Comment: zsh is also reporting an error on `[[ $a = a|b ]]`.

Comment: @isaac, yes, that's the point I'm making here. `a|b` is not a shell _WORD_ here, it's the `a`, `|` and `b` token. Like `echo a|b` doesn't output `a|b` or doesn't expand a `a|b` glob, you need to quote that `|` as it's a special shell character that is invalid in that context. `[[ $a = (a|b) ]]` would work like `echo (a|b)` would work as `(a|b)` is a zsh wildcard operator.

Comment: The wording and explanation on your answer only name bash. That is not the whole truth.

Answer (score 11):

Standard globs ("filename expansion") are: `*`, `?`, and `[ ... ]`. `|` is not a valid glob operator in standard (non-extglob) settings.

Try:

```
shopt -s extglob
[[ a = @(a|b) ]] && echo matched
```

Comment: Thanks. But why isn't `|` intepereted literally?  Why is there a syntax error?

Comment: It wasn't quoted.

Comment: In standard settings, `|` isn't a glob operator, so isn't `|` interpreted literally without being quoted? So why is there a syntax error?

Comment: `|` is a control character; it's never treated as a literal character in the same way that a letter or number is.

Comment: Because in that mode the shell didn't expect a pipe redirect character in the middle of a not-yet-closed [[]]. `[[ $a = a` isn't a valid command whose output can be piped to another process (at least that's what the shell thought you were trying to do).

Comment: Unfortunately, in `[[ a =~ a|b ]]` the `a|b` cannot be quoted. This a good case where the regex should be put into a variable (which *can and should* be quoted) like `re='a|b'; [[ a =~ $re ]] ...`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a regex match the test would be:

```
[[ "$a" =~ a|b ]]
```

Comment: @Tim You should be opening new questions, not continuously editing your current question.

Comment: @gardenhead: My update is to clarify my questions, instead of changing them, in case that you miss it. The second part I added is to show [one comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382214/why-isnt-treated-literally-in-a-glob-pattern/382229?noredirect=1#comment679257_382218)'s pipe explanation about my original question (why the syntax error) is not correct.